# 'So' at start of sentence

Tags: commas

Do you really need to put a comma after the word 'so' at the start of a sentence and, if so, when? Can someone give some examples.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what context you use "so" in.

1. "So" as a quantitative measure (No comma necessary): 
   e.g. "So many people attended the concert last week!"
2. "So" indicating causality (akin to "hence", "therefore", "ergo", "thus"). This requires a comma. 
   e.g. "So, one can easily assume this is true."

Comment: Putting a comma after so in the first sentence changes its meaning.

Comment: And 'so' to indicate identification with what has just been said etc ('So I see' / 'So he says' / 'So I have discovered' ...).